# Where can I find a link to download the SP2 of OES2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, novell, edirectory

I have a Netware Novell server with an eDirectory and different objects configured. I implemented an OEServer2 SP1 to emulate a DSfW to manage the eDirectory with AD.

I join the domain with the Administrator login and I am logged as the Administrator domain. So far, there are no problems.
When I open the MMC window on Windows Server 08 and snap in the "Active Directory Users and Computers" I can see all the OUs and objects presented in the Netware N. server.

But, when I select some OUs I can have an error, and when I select other I don’t have this error.
Error: “Data from XXXXX is not available from Domain Controller OES2.yyyy.local because: The server is unwilling to process the request. Try again later, or choose another DC by selecting Connect to Domain Controller on the Domain context menu.”

With XXXX= OU’s name and yyyy.local= domain name and OES2 server name

If somebody can upload this SP or post a link to download it...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to resolve my problem. I just added the different updates availabled from Yast / Reboot and I can read replicated containers without errors.

But, I have a different problem now. I have this error when I am trying to create a new object on AD:

> "The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints
>   associated with the class of the object."

Probably the eDirectory of Netware server version.. or bad ldpad configurations.

I find a lot of solutions on the Internet. I'll see what I can do for this.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you set a Full Name on the object when you created it?  eDirectory Schema requires a minimum of a Surname to create an object.  Active Directory has a similar requirement, but it is the Full Name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is only one Service Pack (SP1b) for Novell's Open Enterprise Server 2:

[Novell Open Enterprise Server 2 SP1 e-Media Kit](http://download.novell.com/Download?buildid=n6SkQz52x7s~)

Comment: The 1b is because they found some of the packages included were incorrect, and they updated the media to include the new ones.

Comment: SP2 is in closed beta now, as far as I can tell.  But the release date is still a few months out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: And now as time has passed, OES2 SP2 is the current released product, and OES2 SP3 is in closed beta.  Same issues, different numbers.

OES2 SP1 is the current release as noted by splattne.

OES2 SP2 is not yet in closed beta, but ought to be soon. Anyone on that closed beta has signed an NDA agreeing not to spread it around.

What you are asking for is illegal and inappropriate.  If you would like to particpate in the OES2 SP2 beta, you can try and apply an http://beta.novell.com

Comment: And now 8 years later, why is anyone viewing this question? Because it's the oldest unanswered question on Sever Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Now as to the actual problem reported.

What troubleshooting have you tried?

What are you seeing in DSTRace, with the NMAS options enabled?  This is the most likely approach as NMAS is the components used to allow passwords from other systems to be used.  Also, the Kerberos method is part of the NMAS stack.

To learn about using DSTrace, read this excellent article:

[Reading DStrace](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/5681/capturing-and-reading-novell-identity-manager-traces)

The focus is on Identity Manager trace reading, but nonetheless, the importance of Dstrace is made clear.

To read about the process of troubleshooting NMAS related issue via Dstrace you can read my articles:

[AFP/CIFS NMAS troubleshooting](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/7080/example-troubleshooting-afp-nmas-issues)

[pam_ldap NMAS issues](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8438/troubleshooting-pamldap-against-edirectory-issues)

I think the pam_ldap one is not yet published as public, but should be within the next day or three.

Hope these help.

If you are not sure what Dstrace is, you can look at this article:

[Many faces of DSTrace](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/4418/the-many-faces-dstrace)

Answer (score 0):

I probably found a solution here:

http://www.novell.com/support/viewContent.do?externalId=7003431&sliceId=1

I can see there is a modification of this parameter: **`Top $ ndsLoginProperties`** replaced by this: **`ndsLoginProperties`**

Their advice:

> "If Top and ndsLoginProperties `( Top $ ndsLoginProperties )` are both present, please contact Novell Technical Support to have the superclass Top removed from the objectclass Person."

Pure curiosity: do you know what the parameter "TOP" does?

Cheers.

Comment: Top is a super class in the base schema of most directories.

I think it might even be one of the first super classes.  EVERYTHING inherits from Top.  Ok, that is an exaggeration, but I cannot think of anything that does not.   So never extend schema on Top unless you really really mean too.  PS:  You can always edit your original question to add in all the info, instead of posting 'answers'.  This is not meant as a discussion forum, it is meant as Q and A site.